# Why to use IDataReader instead of DbDataReader?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I see an usage of `IDataReader` instead of `DbDataReader` in many examples (and usage of other ADO.NET interfaces instead of their corresponding classes).

I know that `IDataReader` is an interface and `DbDataReader` is a class, and so on and so forth... My question is not about how interfaces differ from classes.

`IDataReader` describes an interface of generic data reader.

`DbDataReader` is also generic (but an abstract class).

Their usage examples seem to be equivalent.

Why to use generic data reader interface instead of using generic data reader class? Which cases require an usage of interface only? Which cases require an usage of class only?

A typical example:

```
DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
.....................
using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    grid.DataSource = reader;
    grid.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `DbDataReader` is also generic

Well, it's *abstract*, but not *generic*.  Probably a semantic argument but it is a *base class* for different readers (`SqlDataReader`, `OleDbDataReader`, etc.)

The main benefit of using the interface over the abstract base class is if someone decided to use a data reader that *doesn't* inherit from `DbDataReader`.

> Which cases require an usage of class only

Concrete classes are always created - interfaces are just used to say "I don't care *what* the concrete class is, so long as it follows the contract with these methods/properties".

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to achieve abstraction in dependencies. Usually we try to use generic interfaces so that classes using that interfaces are independent of actual implementation.

Consider if your class is consuming IDataReader and one day you need to come up with another implementation of IDataReader which may reads data from files, just say as example, then all you need to do is to create another implementation of IDataReader and initialize your instance variable with that.

Plus there are other good practices out there such as [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), [Unit Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) and those are achievable when you code abstracted and interface oriented

Spend some time going through good coding practices such as reading this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131857258)

Comment: You have written the same thing as `D Stanley`, but he has explained it in clear words. So, his reply will be the answer. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

DbDataReader is an abstract class as opposed to an interface.

You can use DbDataReader to intercept value getters using your own derived reader, useful when you need to intercept say the Getters from SqlDataReader for instance

```
public class MyReader : DbDataReader
{
    SqlDataReader _reader;
    public Reader(DbDataReader reader)
    {
        _reader = (SqlDataReader)reader;
    }
    public override string GetString(int ordinal)
    {
        return _reader.GetString(ordinal).Trim();
    }
```

...

```
using(var reader = new MyReader(command.ExecuteReader()))
{
```

...
But this example is not as useful without the DbCommandInterceptor as you would be using this in a more crosscutting way. say you need to Trim() ALL string in a DbContext

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are executed by the runtime differently than derived classes.

Retrieving the getters and setters are less involved than using a derived class because the runtime has to determine which getter or setter is being called.

If a class is defined with no inheritance, the interface way will be faster.
In the new versions of C# where you can define default code this is even more powerful.

Using `IDataReader` allows you to remove direct references to namespaces for `SqlDataReader` or `DbDataReader` in all but the concrete creation of the objects.  This is particularly an issue now with `System.Data.SqlClient` being replaced with `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question should actually be reversed, as interfaces should be preferred over abstract or concrete classes when "exercising" a class.

So, why should you prefer returning a DbDataReader over IDataReader?  When IDataReader  doesn't have the property or method your consumer requires.  The prime one in my opinion is HasRows -- it allows you to check to see if you had results, without actually reading the results.  Depth is another property that is not available, but I've never use it.

IDataReader implements IDataRecord so after a Read it can be cast to IDataRecord for the various GetXXX methods (although personally I prefer an extension method), and the FieldCount property.

Basically, IDataReader is fine in most cases, but there are a couple of things it simply can't do.

Comment: Honestly I cannot say something to you now. This topic was abandoned by me almost 10 yeard ago.

Comment: @Paul: I understand, I added this answer for others, not you.  Mainly to document the short comings of IDataReader, and let others know that if the missing pieces aren't a problem for them, IDataReader should be preferred.